# Is it possible that Darth Sion was actually Lucien Draay?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

As it said in the title, is it possible that [Darth Sion](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Sion) (Lord of Pain) is actually [Lucien Draay](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lucien_Draay) even though that is not said in wiki. It says that Sion fought on Exar Kun's side during the Great Sith war and so on, but there is one scene in Knights of the Old Republic comic where Draay is shown on some random moon where is says that he will embrace his destiny as Lord of Pain, and that is the last scene with him.

[image]

I havent finished with reading, but that just crossed my mind, because the timeline could fit, also Draay could have joined Revan during Mandalorian wars and beyond.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### No.

John Jackson Miller, writer of the *Knights of the Old Republic* comic books, confirmed this [on his website](http://www.farawaypress.com/comics/swknights/swkotor35.html):

> Lucien [in issue 35] tells us what he thinks about being forced into a role created for someone else. The galaxy may get its Darth Sion, but not from him.

The panel in the question is also somewhat misleading, because that's not the end of Lucien's internal monologue; he continues for a little while, and two things are clear when you read the whole thing:

1. When he talks about "embracing his destiny", he's referring to himself in the past tense - rather than describing the current moment, he's describing his state of mind during the incident with Haazen
2. He chose to turn away from the Dark path Haazen was trying to lead him on, and he doesn't intend to return to it

Transcription of the relevant bits from the pages below:

> Haazen got what he wanted. I saw into the Dark Side. I drowned in fire, and while holding the Kressh Gauntlet spared my body - *mostly* - nothing could protect my soul. Betrayal and fury suffocated me - and sustained me. I saw a river leading to a dark world where I might embrace my destiny - as a Lord of Pain. I swam towards it...
>
> But then I thought of my father. I barely knew him, but I knew he *never* accepted any role others had in mind for him.
>
> *[...]*
>
> If we cannot change what *others* will do in the future - we can choose what *we* do. We can choose a different role. We cannot *avert* the prophesied doom - but we can *survive* it.
>
> And we will survive. We may be few, but the Jedi will go on after the tribulations to come. I know this because I am the son of Krynda and Barrison Draay - and at last, I can see my future.
>
> <sup><sub>*Knights of the Old Republic 35: Vindication Part 4*</sub></sup>

[image: Lucien 1]
[image: Lucien 2]
[image: Lucien 3]

Comment: ok, I will go with correct, but that would be nice twist :)

Comment: It should also be noted that Haazen considers "Darth Sion" for Lucien's Sith title.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe Lucien goes back in time during the Exar Kun War and joins the Dark Lord. Self-fulfilling paradox.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, this offers speculation. Please post this as a comment next time (you are almost to the rep level needed to post comments anywhere)

Comment: Then, no. There is no proof that Lucien is Sion. Sion is much older than Lucien.

Comment: Can you [edit] that into your answer in case the comment get deleted?